# 403 error with message:Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project

Tags: php, drupal-7, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api

Can't overcome this situation:
created a project in the Google developers console
they created "Client ID for web application" and "Key for server applications".

In the console requests have completed successfully, but when I send from the server I get the following error:

```
403: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
```

Parameters to construct the query checked..
the request goes on:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy?key=my_key"
pass parameters: "{"items":[{"id":"calendar_id@group.calendar.google.com"}],"timeMax":"2014-04-09T00:00:00+01:00","timeMin":"2014-01-09T00:00:00+01:00","timeZone":"Europe\/Berlin"}"
```

Where can I see what the error is?

Whether in this help Billing (at the moment it is turned off "Billing is not enabled")?

==========================
UPDATED:
The problem was resolved so (like shamanism):
I just created a new project in the google api,
next tab "APIs&auth->Credentials" I added to the project "Client ID for web application",
when you create immediately pointed out "Redirect URIs" when you create is automatically generated "Key for browser applications"that can work with any host).
After these steps, I point to a website created settings and requests are.

To send requests to use drupal and modules: gauth and gcal (which uses http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/).

Comment: It is possible that Google does not accept requests from my site due to the fact that they are sent over http without ssl (https)?

Comment: Managed to solve this:

created in the console a new project,
created the "Client ID for web applications" (pointed to "Redirect URIs", without https),
certificate used the one that created automatically when you create a project ("Referers:
Any referer allowed" probably is bad..but as soon as I specify a site for example: "*.example.com/*" all again falls to the above described error..),
included service "Calendar API".

magic..

Comment: I do have the same problem, can you please update your answer when you found the problem?

Comment: I solved this issue by using the correct ID's it's all explained on another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208870/google-glass-development-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-d/21211489#21211489 . hope this helps you.

Answer (score 25):

I was getting the exact same error (except with the Google Glass Mirror API). Adding billing information and adding both http/https to my redirect URL didn't help either.

Apparently Google APIs have been known to misbehave when you provide both OAuth2 credentials and an API Key! The solution (if you are using the Google APIs Client Library for PHP) is to simply remove the following from your code:

```
$client->setDeveloperKey($key);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This may not be marked as the answer - but it's solved the problem for me! I'm using release 1.0.3-beta with the [Hello World tutorial here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api). ...although that tutorial is currently fairly out of date...

Comment: This also fixed my issue. using the calendar api and was setting both the ApiKey in the calendarservicerequest as well as specifying OauthToken. removing the ApiKey fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I got exactly the same error. In my case, I was trying to access "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people", and 'Google+ API' was not enabled for my project in API's section. I just had to set 'Google+ API' ON

Answer (score 2):

Try to edit allowed referrers in the developers console, like they say here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/22870082/getting-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-console-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870082/getting-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-console-t)

This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Public API access for action, you must to add your server ip to Allowed IPs list (Select Project -> APIs and Auth -> Credentials). If not, you will get an error as above: "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."

Please view my attached file to view more 
[image]