# Google Authentication Using PHP Library OAuth 2.0

Tags: php, api, google-plus

After many many hours searching I am still unable to figure out why I am receiving this error. It worked for a month and without touching any code, stopped working last night. The web app has been registered and Google+ api is turned on.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?key=MYKEY: (403) Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.'

I enabled Google+ Domain API just to see if it did anything. It allowed me to login 1 time and then continued to fail after that.

Comment: This answer may help you:http://stackoverflow.com/a/21223101/2777820

Comment: I have that in my code. I enabled Google+ Domains API just to check. It worked 1 time, then when I tried again it did not work. This is very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer key should be OK to pass every time as long as it matches the project that has been used for sign in (e.g. the client ID and the key come from the same developers.google.com/console project).

There was a problem yesterday with the userinfo endpoint that caused 403 for a number of users - that has now been resolved, but my guess is you were hitting that unfortunately!

Comment: Perfect! I thought I was going crazy. Is there a place I can see current problems that may cause errors?

Answer (score 0):

So after further research and testing, I think I have the solution.

As mentioned by Jason OOO, $client->setDeveloperKey($key); was causing the problem.

As it turns out, Google PHP library needs $client->setDeveloperKey($key); passed the first time for validation, but causes an error if passed again after already being validated.

So, to fix this problem, check to see if user is already logged in and if they are do not pass $client->setDeveloperKey($key);