# Google Maps Geolocation API for Android

Tags: android, google-api

I want to use the [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation) in an Android application. I followed the instructions and got this error:

```
httpResponse : {
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "usageLimits",
                "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
                "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
    }
}
```

I'm using an Android key for accessing the API but I found in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#not_purchased) that :

> Click either **Create new Browser key** or **Create new Server key** and
>   follow the prompts.

So, can we use the Google Maps Geolocation API with an Android key or do we really need a Browser or Server Key?

**Edit:** Here is my usage limits.

[image]

Comment: have you Enable  `Google Maps Geolocation API` ..? if not You have exceeded your daily limit , of using that API

Comment: Yes, `Google Maps Geolocation API` is enabled. I edited my post to add the usage limits.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020898/403-error-with-messageaccess-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-conso

and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870082/getting-error-403-access-not-configured-please-use-google-developers-console-t?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got it. I created a Browser key with any referer allowed and it worked. The `Google Maps Geolocation API` can't be access with an Android key.